# Emacs: AUCTeX-LaTeX compilation error

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I have been using LaTeX with Emacs and AUCTeX for 2 years and I haven't run into any problem. However, yesterday when I tried to compile the master file LaTeX gave me a strange error:

> ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:\303\lst@FillFixed@ not set up for use
>
> --- TeX said ---
>   with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.963 magicamente, è
>                        ancora intatto. È una struttura solidamente costruita

I think the problem is the encoding format (`è` `È`) but I don't understand why this problem happens only for one "subordinated" file and not for the others.

The encoding I use is UTF-8 and is set both in my `.emacs` file and in the LaTeX master file. Moreover, the mode line says `U`, which indicates UTF-8 is used as an encoding for the buffer.

Do you have any suggestions for resolving my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If that `303` is supposed to be the unicode point for è or È, then I think something is wrong.  It should be 232 (0xE8) resp. 200 (0xC8).  Have you tried re-entering those characters?

Comment: I have repalced all the incriminated character but LaTex give to me always the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

That has some limitations - see [Icelandic, utf8 and utf8x in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797841/icelandic-utf8-and-utf8x-in-latex)